# Homework - combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

How many solutions does this inequality have in non negative integers $x_i$:

$n \leq x_1+x_2+x_3+ \dots +x_n \le 2n$ ? Im stumped

I know I should add another variable but...I don't know.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking...

Comment: How many different combinatios are there for x(1) x(2) etc that are non negative and integer, that satisfy this inequality

Comment: u mean $x_1 + x_2 + ... x_n$   ???

Comment: yes! I just don't know how to write it in mathjax :P

Comment: You want the number different combinations of non-negative integers $x_1,\dots,x_n$ such that $n\leq x_1+\dots+x_n \leq 2n$?

Comment: Read it http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?lq=1

Comment: Yes doppz thats exactly the question

Comment: What have you tried so far? I would suggest breaking up into cases based on how many $x_i=0$.

Comment: Isn't this "Stirling numbers of the second kind" problem ?  I m just asking.I m not sure myself. NO it is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $s$ is  positive integer.  Now create a row of $n + s - 1$ blanks, and imagine you have $s-1$ $o$s and $n-1$ $x$s  .  There are ${n+s-1 \choose n-1}$ ways to position the $x$s in the blanks.  There is one way to position the $o$s.  Each of these permutations represents a solution to the equation
$$\sum_{k=1}^n x_k = s, \qquad x_k \ge 0, 1\le k \le n.$$
This correspondence is achieved by letting $x_1$ be the number of $o$s as the beginning, $x_2$, be the number of $o$s between $x_1$ and $x_2$, etc.
So this equation has ${n+s-1\choose n-1}$ solutions.

Now do some summation to get the solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Using generating functions,

The number of solutions of $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + \dots + x_n = m$ is given by the coefficient of $x^m$ in $(1+x+x^2+...)^n = \dfrac1{(1-x)^n}$

So the number of solutions of $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + \dots + x_n \le m$ is given by the coefficient of $x^m$ in $\dfrac1{(1-x)^{n+1}}$.  Say this is $f(m)$.  Then you need $f(2n)-f(n-1)$.

By the extended binomial theorem, $f(m) = \dfrac{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)\dots(n+m)}{m!} = \binom{n+m}{m}$, so you can work out that 
$$f(2n)-f(n-1) = \binom{3n}{n}-\binom{2n-1}{n}$$ is what you seek.

Comment: +1 Though, this can be approached directly with stars and bars without generating functions. It's an overkill.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** The number of (non-negative integer) solutions to

$$ x_1 + x_2 + \ldots + x_n \leq k, $$

is equal to the number of solutions to

$$x_1 + x_2 + \ldots + x_n + x_{n+1} = k, $$

which by stars and bars is ${ n+1 + k -1  \choose n}.$ $_\square$

Hence, conclude that the number of ways is ${3n \choose n } - { 2n-1  \choose n}$.

Comment: Yes, that's simpler. +1